# Add / Remove key-value pairs from a Map

Tags: elixir

How to add (and remove) key-value pairs in an Elixir map? This does not work:

```rb
map = %{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

map[:d] = 4
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

### Add to Map

Use [`Map.put(map, key, value)`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#put_new/3):

```ex
map = Map.put(map, :d, 4)
#=> %{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
```

---

### Remove from Map

Use [`Map.delete(map, key)`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#delete/2):

```ex
map = Map.delete(map, :b)
#=> %{a: 1, c: 3}
```

Comment: What about prepending?

Comment: Maps do not preserve the order of keys. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40408469/1533054

Answer (score 38):

## Your issue

**Don't forget that variables are immutable in Elixir.**

So the following code doesn't make sense, because you can't directly change `map` or `map[:d]`'s value like this:

```rb
map[:d] = 4
```

## Solution

Here are the functions you can use instead:

- **[`Map.put(map, key, value)`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#put_new/3) adds an element to a map**
- **[`Map.delete(map, key)`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#delete/2) removes an element from a map**

## How to use these functions?

Since Elixir variables are immutable, **these functions return a new map**, instead of directly changing your map. Example:

```rb
iex(1)> map = %{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
%{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
iex(2)> Map.put(map, :d, 4)
%{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
iex(3)> map
%{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3} # map is unchanged
```

So if you want to "change" your map, you need to replace your old `map`variable by the new map returned by `Map.put()` or `Map.delete()`. Example:

```rb
iex(1)> map = %{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
%{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
iex(2)> map = Map.put(map, :d, 4)
%{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
iex(3)> map = Map.delete(map, :a)
%{b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
```

Comment: @Sheharyar gave a correct answer, but I prefer this answer that emphasizes on immutability in elixir, a subtle notion, that I had trouble to wrap my head around. answers like this one are always enlightening to me.

Comment: Yes. An answer is better when it not only addresses the original question, but points to what's likely not yet well understood.

Answer (score 3):

#### Inserting Multiple Key-Value Pairs

If you have an [`Enumerable`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enumerable.html) of key-value pairs, you can use [`Map.new/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#new/1) to create a new map:

```rb
iex> values = [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]
[a: 1, b: 2, c: 3]
iex> Map.new(values)
%{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

To add to an existing map, maps implement the [`Collectable`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Collectable.html) protocol, so you can use [`Enum.into/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#into/2):

```rb
iex> map = %{existing: "value"}
%{existing: "value"}
iex> Enum.into(values, map)
%{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, existing: "value"}
```

Or alternatively use a [comprehension](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1-the-into-and-uniq-options):

```rb
iex> for {k, v} <- values, into: map, do: {k, v}
%{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, existing: "value"}
```

---

#### Deleting Multiple Keys

For dropping multiple keys at once, there is [`Map.drop/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#drop/2):

```rb
iex> map = %{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5}
%{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5}
iex> Map.drop(map, [:a, :c])
%{b: 2, d: 4, e: 5}
```

Comment: "Note that passing a non-empty list as the collectable is deprecated" - https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Enum.html#into/2

Comment: These examples are passing a map as the collectable, not a non-empty list.

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing out the difference