# how to insert multi key-values into map simply?

Tags: elixir

before keys insert, the map is as follows:

```
%{
  "csv" => %Plug.Upload{
    content_type: "text/csv",
    filename: "test.csv",
    path: "/var/folders/vt/hg77q0c112dbh9dphnccm5rc0000gp/T/plug-1665/multipart-1665996444-407934624070418-7"
  },
  "external_base_directory" => "12",
  "id" => "",
  "importer_id" => "1",
  "internal_base_directory" => "12"
}
```

After inserted, the map is as follows:

```
chnageset batch before: %{
  "csv" => %Plug.Upload{
    content_type: "text/csv",
    filename: "test.csv",
    path: "/var/folders/vt/hg77q0c112dbh9dphnccm5rc0000gp/T/plug-1665/multipart-1665996444-407934624070418-7"
  },
  "csv_file_name" => "test.csv",
  "external_base_directory" => "12",
  "id" => "",
  "importer_id" => "1",
  "internal_base_directory" => "12",
  "internal_csv_path" => "/var/folders/vt/hg77q0c112dbh9dphnccm5rc0000gp/T/plug-1665/multipart-1665996444-407934624070418-7"
}
```

My code is as follows:

```
batch_params_new =
        Map.put(Map.put(batch_params, "csv_file_name", file_name), "internal_csv_path", file_path)
```

Is it possible to simplify the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add / Remove key-value pairs from a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251295/add-remove-key-value-pairs-from-a-map)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Map.merge/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#merge/2) is your friend.

```
batch_params_new =
  Map.merge(batch_params,
    %{"csv_file_name" => file_name,
      "internal_csv_path" => file_path, …})
```

---

*Sidenote:* As for several puts, we usually use pipe `|>/2` rather than nested calls in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir)

```elixir
batch_params_new =
  batch_params
  |> Map.put("csv_file_name", file_name)
  |> Map.put("internal_csv_path", file_path)
```

Comment: I like the second method, and it is much more beautiful.

Comment: Well, if there are two values to put, then yes, but imagine you have 20 of them. `Ma[p.merge/2` is still a single call.